# Adjusting non local time

Tags: vb.net

The Requirement: 
I have local times for events. These events are in Australian states. I would like to convert these local times to my local time. Including Daylight saving (DLS). I figure I would need to know the UCT offset for each state (location) on that day and then my local UCT offset on that day and from that adjust the events' local time to my local time. Say I live in NSW and the event is in WA. The local WA time is 2pm that makes it 4pm my time. Or 5pm during DLS.

The Problem: How do I obtain the UCT offset for the locations. There are ways to obtain my local machine UTC offset, but that is only half of the picture. Also from historical point of view I may need to look at old or future events so its not always just todays' events I need adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this stuff can help: using googleapis:
google maps documentation of timezone
make request to get time offset( as I understand in seconds.

Or

you can make array from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
and by state find time offset DLS they have another one

or what about this one:
TimeZone.GetUtcOffset Method (DateTime)
.NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. The google is an external reference which I would like to avoid if I can help it. The other list is a great resource but does not indicate if location is in DLS or not. The timezone .net option appears local time dependent and is not aware of past or present DLS settings.

Comment: well, I am not sure but TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime get as argument DataTime where you can specify from your array(which you can make from wiki) and here is description:   `Public Function IsDaylightSavingTime (
 dateTime As Date
) As Boolean
` and it’s will say if you DateTime object is in DLS or not